# Group multilevel ArrayList jasperreports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a object which contains an ArrayList with "Group" objects. Every Group object have a ArrayList of "Table" objects and these objects have a ArrayList with "Field" objects. All these object have their own properties as well like "name" etc.

I want to render this object in jasper reports but I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate and group by Group's name and Table name and then iterate through the fields..

Not really sure how I should pass the object to the report and how I should handle it.

The result in my report should look something like this.

```
GroupA
  GroupA information 

    Table A object name and version
      Field1, properties... 
      Field2, properties...

    Table B Object name and version
     Field1, properties... 
     Field2, properties...

Group B
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your data to the report by wrapping it in a JRBeanCollectionDataSource.  That would iterate groups in the report detail band.

To further iterate on sublists, you can use lists, tables or subreports (also passing the sublists by wrapping them in JRBeanCollectionDataSource).